# First click modal doesn't open in .NET 5 Blazor server side

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap-4, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-5

After loading a page, the very first click on any card doesn't open the modal window, but the next click and after, it will lunch the modal as it expected. I am not sure what caused this issue.

```
<div class="card-columns">
    @foreach (var project in ProjectService.GetProjects())
    {
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-img" @onclick="(e => SelectProject(project.Id))" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#projectModal" style="background-image: url('@project.Image'); cursor: pointer;"></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">@project.Title</h5>
        </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>

    @if (selectedProject != null)
{
<div class="modal fade" id="projectModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="projectTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
...
```

C#:

```
              @code { 
                    Project selectedProject;
                    string selectedProjectId;
                    void SelectProject(string projectId)
                    {
                        selectedProjectId = projectId;
                        selectedProject = ProjectService.GetProjects().First(x => x.Id == projectId);
                        Console.WriteLine("hi");
                    }
```

The very first click, it reads the Console.WriteLine but doesn't show the modal, so I know selectedProject is not null and it suppose to show the modal. I tried to comment out all the javascript code I had and still have the issue. I also downloaded a new copy of bootstrap and replaced it into my project since I replaced some of the values (mostly fonts) by mistake and I found out that I should never edit the bootsrap. Still have the issue. There is also no console error in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this is not quite right, and I would say it's a lazy way to fix this issue because I still don't know what the root of the issue was, but I solved my problem by introducing a mouseover event to the card-img div:

```
<div class="card-img" @onclick="(e => SelectProject(project.Id))" @onmouseover="(e => start(project.Id))" data-toggle="modal">
```

C#

```
bool unlock;
void start(string projectId)
{
  if (!unlock)
  {
    selectedProjectId = projectId;
    selectedProject = ProjectService.GetProjects().First(x => x.Id == projectId);
    unlock = true;
  }
}
```

Now for the first time and only once when the mouse is going over a card, it will run the open modal but since it doesn't open for the first attempt, it basically does nothing but also make it interactable with the first click attempt.